# OR statement handling two != clauses Python

Tags: python, operator-keyword, clause

(Using Python 2.7) I understand this is pretty elementary but why wouldn't the following statement work as written:

```
input = int(raw_input())
while input != 10 or input != 20:
    print 'Incorrect value, try again'
    bet = int(raw_input())
```

Basically I only want to accept 10 or 20 as an answer. Now, regardless of 'input', even 10, or 20, I get 'Incorrect value'. Are these clauses self conflicting? I thought that the OR statement would say OK as long as one of the clauses was correct. Thanks!

Comment: Note: it is best not to use a variable name that then redefines the builtin "input" function. Rename it. ("answer" might be good).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need **`and`**:

```
while input != 10 and input != 20:
```

Think it through: If the `input` is `10`, then the first expression is `false`, causing Python to evaluate the second expression `input != 20`. `10` is different form `20`, so this expressions evaluates to `true`. As `false or true == true`, the whole expression is `true`.
Same for `20`.

Comment: Thanks for the full logic stepping. It appears as though I had a bit(heh) of logic dyslexia.

Answer (score 10):

....or a different way to express it that may seem more natural to you:

```
while input not in (10, 20):
    # your code here...
```

Comment: You're right, I actually like this much better than the latter. Thanks too!

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to have the `bet` be `input`. And I think you meant to say if input if not 10 and is not 20.

```
input = int(raw_input())
while input != 10 and input != 20:
    print 'Incorrect value, try again'
    input = int(raw_input())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an `and` there.

```
while input != 10 or input != 20:
```

This will repeat forever - if `input` is 10, then the first condition is false. if `input` is 20, the second condition is false. `input` can never be both 10 and 20, so that's equivalent to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You want "and" and not "or". Think about your boolean logic.